# Why didn't the PPP government of pakistan face any problem from the military?

Tags: government, military, pakistan

Between 2008 and 2013, the [Pakistan Peoples Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan_Peoples_Party) government engaged in several high profile disputes with the military

1. Osama bin Laden capture
2. memogate scandal + Hussain Haqqani's release
3. Raymond Davis incident

Why didn't the PPP government of Pakistan face any problem from the military?

Comment: What do you mean by 'obl capture'?

Comment: Ok, I've worked it out: obl=Osama bin Laden.

Comment: The question is unclear to me.  It lists several PPP-military disputes, and then asks why the two didn't have any problems, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What would qualify as "any problem"? The question makes it clear that there have been multiple disputes with the military. What precisely are you wondering about? A coup? Public statements from military leaders? I fear this question might tend towards hypotheticals.